# How to get the value of $A + B ?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

I have this statement:

> If $\frac{x+6}{x^2-x-6} = \frac{A}{x-3} + \frac{B}{x+2}$, what is the value of $A+B$ ?

My attempt was:

$\frac{x+6}{(x-3)(x+2)} = \frac{A(x+2) + B(x-3)}{(x-3)(x+2)}$

$x+6=(x+2)A + B(x-3)$: But from here, I don't know how to get $A + B$, any hint is appreciated.

Comment: $x+6=x(A+B)+2A-3B$ so $1=A+B$ and $6=2A-3B$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, This "algebraic trick", can I always do it?, per example in $x+3y+4z+5 = x(a_1+...+a_n) + y(b_1 + ... + b_n) + z(c_1+...c_n) + p+q+d $, I can safely say that $a_1 + ... +a_ n = 1$, $b_1 + ... + b_n = 3$, $c_1 + ... + c_n = 4$ and $p+q+d=5$?

Comment: It makes a lot of sense since, $a1+...+a_n$ they are the only variables involved with $x$, then they must necessarily be equal to the coefficient of $x$, right?

Comment: yes, it's [equating coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equating_coefficients)

Comment: Thanks for that reference!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x+6=(x+2)A+B(x-3)$ then $$x+6=x(A+B)+(2A-3B)\implies$$ $$A+B=1\text{ and } 2A-3B=6$$

Answer (score 3):

Put $x=-2$ and $x=3$ to get $B=-\frac{4}{5}$ and $A=\frac{9}{5}$ respectively.

Comment: Where to put these values?

Comment: In the last equation of OP.

Comment: OK, I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By equating coefficients, you have the system of equations
$$A+B = 1,$$
$$2A-3B = 6.$$

Answer (score 0):

By your work the coefficient before $x$ it's $1$, which ends.

Also,  $$\frac{x+6}{x^2-x-6}=\frac{x+6}{(x-3)(x+2)}=\frac{x-3+9}{(x-3)(x+2)}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{x+2}+\frac{9}{5}\left(\frac{1}{x-3}-\frac{1}{x+2}\right)=\frac{\frac{9}{5}}{x+3}+\frac{-\frac{4}{5}}{x+2},$$
which gives $A+B=1.$